# All views look like they're selected

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-storyboard

I don't know what I did in Xcode, but suddenly all views look like they're selected with those blue borders. How can I disable that?

[image: All views look like they're selected]

Comment: Which version of Xcode you're using?

Comment: @Imad Xcode 8.3.2

Comment: Editor > Canvas..only check the show constraints option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Editor
  ---->Canvas

Check Show Constraints and

Uncheck Show Bounds Rectangles

[image]